# Negative values for Wait Time per Core per Sec in sp_BlitzFirst

Tags: sql-server-2016, monitoring, wait-types, sp-blitzfirst

I'm a developer in a firm that doesn't want to spend money on a DBA so i'm on my own with keeping the SQL servers healty. I checked some of Brent's videos and decided to check how hard the SQL servers are working.
I used sp_blitzFirst (sp_BlitzFirst 2017-07-01 00:00:00.0000000 +00:00) within a SQL agent job, that is executed every 3 minutes whole day. No special parameters, just table names to let the procedure know where to store the data.

SQL Server is 2016 with Service Pack 1 (13.0.4001.0)

So far i really like the output because it tells me when the server is idling...and when it's working. I am confused though because i get some negative numbers in the "wait time per core per sec". How should i interpret that?

[image: first ocurrence]
[image: second ocurrence]

Comment: I can only assume that these are cumulative waits, which are deducted from the newest values, and if it happens that particular core had 0 waits during the latest scan it will show you negative value.